# Standard deviation of random temperatures

Tags: java, statistics, variance

I am trying to calculate a standard deviation for x amount of random temperatures based on a text file containing 50,000+ temperatures.

I have an array containing sample sizes for each index that I am supposed to load into. For example, 8 random temperatures into index 0, 16 random temperatures into index 1, etc.

I have successfully calculated the sample mean, but I am having trouble with the variance/standard deviation.

```
private static void calcEstimates() {
    double 
        sum,
        mean,
        sampleSize = 0,
        mnSum = 0,
        mnSqrSum = 0;

    double [] means = new double[numTemps]; 

    for ( i = 0; i < sampleSizes.length; i++) {
        sum = 0;
        sampleSize = sampleSizes[i];
        for (j = 0; j < sampleSize; j++)
            sum += allTemps[rng.nextInt(numTemps)];

        mean = sum / sampleSize;
        mnSum += sum * sum;
        mnSqrSum = (sampleSizes[i] * mnSum - sum * sum) / (sampleSizes[i]*(sampleSizes[i]-1));

        sampleMeans[i]  = sum/sampleSize;;
        sampleStdDevs[i] = Math.sqrt(mnSqrSum);
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Sample Std Dev should be around ~20 for each sample size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of the *(arithmetic) mean* (see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean) is:

[image]

and for the *standard deviation* (see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation):

[image]

In the code below, the mean is calculated in the first step and the standard deviation in the second step:

```
private static void calcEstimates() {
    int sampleSize;
    double sum;
    double mean;
    double sumSqrDev;
    double stdDev;

    System.out.println("size   mean      stdDev");
    System.out.println("------------------------");
    for (int i = 0; i < sampleSizes.length; i++) {

        sum = 0;
        sampleSize = sampleSizes[i];

        // 1. Step: Calculation of the mean
        double[] temps = new double[sampleSize]; // N
        for (int j = 0; j < sampleSize; j++) {
            temps[j] = allTemps[rng.nextInt(numTemps)];
            sum += temps[j];
        }

        mean = sum / sampleSize;

        // 2. Step: Calculation of the standard deviation
        sumSqrDev = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < sampleSize; j++) {
            sumSqrDev += Math.pow((temps[j] - mean), 2);
        }

        stdDev = Math.sqrt(sumSqrDev / (sampleSize - 1));

        System.out.printf("%5d  %.4f  %.4f\n", sampleSize, mean, stdDev);
    }
}
```

In the following example the temperature is *uniformly* distributed with values between `a = 450` and `b = 550`:

```
private static int[] sampleSizes = new int[] {8,16,32,64,128,140,160,200,240,280,320,360,400,20000};
private static Random rng = new Random();
private static int numTemps = 20000;
private static double[] allTemps = new double[numTemps]; 
private static double meanTemperature = 500;
private static double deviation = 100;

private static void initTemperatures() {        
    for (int i = 0; i < numTemps; i++) {
        allTemps[i] = meanTemperature + deviation * (rng.nextDouble() - 0.5);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    initTemperatures();
    calcEstimates();
}
```

Thus, the *theoretical* mean value is

[image]

and the *theoretical* standard deviation is

[image]

(see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous) and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35123/whats-the-difference-between-variance-and-standard-deviation) in good agreement with the result of the code:

```
size   mean      stdDev
------------------------
    8  504.8617  32.1182
   16  503.5508  31.2777
   32  503.1226  28.3134
   64  504.2420  28.2647
  128  499.5431  27.3515
  140  504.0203  26.6482
  160  501.0673  28.7222
  200  498.4244  28.5140
  240  500.7214  28.6428
  280  497.3849  28.3684
  320  499.5752  28.8653
  360  500.6975  29.1524
  400  500.5515  29.9879
20000  499.7810  28.9035
```